# Where is XSLProcessorContext in the JAXP

Tags: java, xslt, xalan, jaxp

I would like to get rid of `xalan.jar` (version 2.7.0) dependency in one of our old projects and use xalan which is included into `JRE 1.7.0_51`.

However there is an extension java class in that project which imports `org.apache.xalan.extensions.XSLProcessorContext` and `org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemExtensionCall` classes.

I cannot find those classes in the JRE and I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Does Oracle include just a part of xalan into JRE or those classes are already depreciated and now the custom mapping should be done differently?

Comment: In that case you'd be better off sticking with xalan.jar - if the equivalent class is there at all in the JRE built in processor then it'll be in a com.sun internal package and there's no guarantee it'll stay in the same place from one version to another.